# Central Heating Inhibitor for underfloor heating?

Tags: heating, gas, boiler

I am getting quotes for annual gas boiler service. The guy was talking about adding central heating inhibitor. I have underfloor heating (gas), which he knows.

Would you still use central heating inhibitor (do you use the same product for both applications?)

Comment: I imagine you are talking about a rust/corrosion inhibitor.  It will probably mix in the water so it will go though the whole system, unless the under floor system is separated/closed off from the boiler water.

Comment: That is needed if it is a recirculating system. If it is a potable water system do not add anything.